# Unity Config with MVC 5 - RegisterInstance - passing IPrincipal as Constructor to method not taking network username

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

Unity Config with MVC 5. How to get NetworkUsername in UnityConfig.cs?

On Calling `container.RegisterInstance` - the constructor of the accepts IPrincipal as parameter?

Tried `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` - all are returning IISPOOL identity, but I need network username.

I can't call `container.RegisterType<IService1, Service1>();` because I need to pass `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` as constructor default value.

Comment: add more code, please

Comment: also, I don't understand. you need to get principal of user who loads a page?

Comment: we need more information (code) for help